# .Net cross-platform user impersonation

Tags: .net, cross-platform, impersonation

I'm creating a .Net 6 console application which involves reading/writing files to user-specified file paths. Sometimes these file paths are on network shares which require separate credentials to be accessed with. If I was only worried about running on Windows I would use [WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-6.0). As it's name implies though, and by looking at the sample code which contains the line `[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`, I'm pretty certain this will only work on Windows, and not Linux or MacOS.

Is there a cross-platform function in .Net 6 (or some other 3rd party library perhaps) that can be used for user impersonation so I can do things like `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` on network shares that require different credentials?